# upload multiple photos

Tags: php

I have a form which I am using to upload users photos but the problem is that I can upload 1 photos each time .like facebook I want my users to select multiple images in one shot. can anyone please guide. here is my present code.

```
<tr><td><input type="file" name="photos[]" /></td><td><input type="text" size="35" name="descriptions[]" /></td></tr>
```

and php is processing the uploaded images. can you please tell how should I do so that multiple images can be selected and uploaded in one shot

Comment: there is not much your present code, you know

Comment: Have you tried a flash uploader or HTML5 API file uploader?

Comment: duplicate of 100500 already asked questions though

Comment: @ehime: Erm? It is not your job to undo other people's right to vote. Upvote if you think that this is a _great_ question, not because you disagreed with somebody's downvote.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So you downvote me with a correct answer, code and method?

Comment: @ehime: I haven't downvoted you. What makes you think I did?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nothing but someone did, seriously though, this is why I don't try to help people with their coding.

Comment: @ehime: Well it wasn't me. And why take it out on the OP? If you don't want to help then you don't have to; but you did, which is great, and you should be happy about that regardless of what "points" you get out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing is you need to make your form multipart

```
<form method="post" action="where_ever" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And if you use HTML5 the next part is to create a named array

```
<input type="file" accept='image/*' name="multiImageUpload[]" id="multiImageUpload" />
<input type="file" accept='image/*' name="multiImageUpload[]" id="multiImageUpload" />
<input type="file" accept='image/*' name="multiImageUpload[]" id="multiImageUpload" />
```

This will put all files into a $_POST array called multiImageUpload.

In order to allow a name to accept multiples in an array you need to use [] 
at the back of name, `name[] or images[] or files[]`, also using the HTML5
property `multiple` `multiple=''` or `multiple='multiple'` will allow you 
to select multiple files at once form a single input.

Here's some working sample code to play around with

The HTML

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name='uploads[]' type="file" multiple=""/>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

The PHP

```
foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['name'] as $filename) {
    echo '<li>' . $filename . '</li>';
}

// full contents of $_FILS
echo '<pre>';
var_export($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Not a problem, glad it helps.

Comment: i want to select multiple images with one box.in your case three boxes are there and for each box i have to browse and select images. i want from one box i will browse image folder and just by dragging i will select multiple images . can you please guide for that

Comment: Use the html and php example, it uses only one box to select multiple images. that's what `multiple=''` does.